# how to reduce Flash CS5 swf file size after adding button

Tags: flash-cs5

i don't work on Flash much but i've made a small banner ad for a client...
its a simple banner with 3 images in it and a button with some actionscript linking to an external campaign monitor.

the target file size is about 70kb.
image compression is turned on in the publish settings.

without the button the file size is fine.
when i add a basic button in with a an event listener and about 5 lines of code the published swf size jumps up to over 200kb...

i've tried deleting the button and it drops back to 70kb...

anyone know what i can do to include a button but also keep the file size reasonably small?

cheers

dog

Comment: update : problem solved.... 
looks like it was just flash cs5 acting weird... opened the file in cs6 and published ... the file size went down to a very respectable 40kb...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using text in your button and have you embedded the font? That can really bloat an swf.
What you can try is either break the text apart so you don't need to embed the font (but it makes editing a lot of work)
Or you embed only the characters you have actually typed in the button.

If that is not the problem, please post any more details you can think of, including the code.

Comment: thanks for the reply...
no text, nt even any image for the button... its simply a transparent button with a 'hit' which covers the whole animation...
the code looks like this :
[pre]import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 // ......
 but1.addEventListener(
  MouseEvent.CLICK,
     function(event: MouseEvent) : void {
     flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest( root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank");
     }
  );[/pre]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any images in Flash Library that has Linkage id assigned to it. Remove the linkage id and publish swf.

Comment: thanks for the comment... unfortunatly it really doesn't seem to be the images whihc are bumping up the size... with just the basic animation (ibncluding images) its 70kb... when i add a simple transparent button it publishes at 200kb... remove the button it drops down again...

Comment: Check by deleting ASO files through 'Control -> Delete ASO Files and Test Movie' before publishing the swf.

Answer (score 0):

well, it looks like it was a bug in CS5... i tried opening the banner in flash CS6 and did the same procedure of creating the button and giving it an action... published it and it was now approx 40kb...

very odd.